# Binding to dependency property in slider control style not working

Tags: c#, wpf, slider, dependency-properties

All the default property bindings are working fine however my custom properties are using the fallback values. Specifically ColorThumb and ColorThumbBorder. As their names imply, these 2 properties color the respective parts of the slider's thumb using a brush.

I've had no problems in the past getting my styles to use custom properties for other controls. Is there something unique about the slider control?

**Style Xaml**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DMSlider}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
                <Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TickBar x:Name="TopTick" Visibility="{TemplateBinding TickPlacement}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Placement="Top" Height="4" Grid.Row="0"/>
                        <TickBar x:Name="BottomTick" Visibility="{TemplateBinding TickPlacement}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Placement="Bottom" Height="4" Grid.Row="0"/>
                        <Border x:Name="TrackBackground" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0" Margin="5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="4.0" Grid.Row="1"
                                Background="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                                BorderBrush="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}">
                            <Canvas Margin="-6,-1">
                                <Rectangle Visibility="Hidden" x:Name="PART_SelectionRange" Height="4.0" StrokeThickness="1.0"/>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Border>
                        <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1">
                            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource DMSliderRepeatButton}"/>
                            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource DMSliderRepeatButton}"/>
                            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                            <Track.Thumb>
                                <Thumb x:Name="Thumb">
                                    <Thumb.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
                                            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                                        <Border x:Name="gripBorder" BorderThickness="1"
                                                                Background="{Binding ColorThumb, 
                                                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=Red}"
                                                                BorderBrush="{Binding ColorThumbBorder, 
                                                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=Green}" >
                                                            <Rectangle x:Name="grip" Height="15" Width="10" />
                                                        </Border>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Thumb.Style>
                                </Thumb>
                            </Track.Thumb>
                        </Track>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Properties CS**

```
public partial class DMSlider : Slider
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorSliderLeftProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ColorSliderLeft", typeof(Brush), typeof(DMSlider));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorSliderRightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ColorSliderRight", typeof(Brush), typeof(DMSlider));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorSliderThumbProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ColorThumb", typeof(Brush), typeof(DMSlider), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Orange));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorSliderThumbHoverProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ColorThumbHover", typeof(Brush), typeof(DMSlider));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorSliderThumbBorderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ColorThumbBorder", typeof(Brush), typeof(DMSlider));

    public Brush ColorSliderLeft
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ColorSliderLeftProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColorSliderLeftProperty, value); }
    }

    public Brush ColorSliderRight
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ColorSliderRightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColorSliderRightProperty, value); }
    }

    public Brush ColorThumb
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ColorSliderThumbProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColorSliderThumbProperty, value); }
    }

    public Brush ColorThumbHover
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ColorSliderThumbHoverProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColorSliderThumbHoverProperty, value); }
    }

    public Brush ColorThumbBorder
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ColorSliderThumbProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColorSliderThumbBorderProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: `RelativeSource TemplatedParent` in the ControlTemplate of a Thumb references the Thumb, not the DMSlider. You may perhaps use `RelativeSource AncestorType=local:DMSlider` instead.

Comment: I looked up how to use AncestorType but I'm getting errors, could you provide an example please? Also, wouldn't I want to target the thumb since it's the object I'm trying to style with the property?

Comment: Target of the Binding is the Border in the ControlTemplate of a Thumb, target properties are the bound properties of the Border. But source of the Binding should be DMSlider, not the TemplatedParent.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you, you've solved the issue for me. Please post an answer that I can accept.

Comment: You know you can write an answer yourself? Since RelativeSource wih AncestorType didn't seem to work for you, it may make sense if you write what actually worked.

Comment: @Clemens It did work for me once I figured out the correct syntax. That's why I want you to post an answer. I could reply with my own answer but I would just be repeating what you told me and taking credit away from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Clemens for showing me what I was doing wrong. I needed to reference the slider not the the thumb.

I should have been targeting an ancestor like so:

```
Background="{Binding ColorThumb, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:DMSlider}, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=Red}"
BorderBrush="{Binding ColorThumbBorder, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:DMSlider}, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=Green}"
```

**Full thumb style**

```
<Thumb x:Name="Thumb">
<Thumb.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Border x:Name="gripBorder" BorderThickness="1"
                            Background="{Binding ColorThumb, 
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:DMSlider}, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=Red}"
                            BorderBrush="{Binding ColorThumbBorder, 
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:DMSlider}, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=Green}">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="grip" Height="15" Width="10" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Thumb.Style>
```